# HTML img crossorigin="use-credentials" simple example

Tags: html, node.js, image, cors

I cloned the http server with: `git clone https://github.com/http-party/http-server`

In a terminal I execute the command: `node ./bin/http-server --username test --password image --cors`

The http server is now running on http://localhost:8080 and I see the landing page successfully

When I go to http://localhost:8080/img/turtle.png then I am prompted for **username** and **password**.

When I enter `test` and `image` then I see the turtle successfully.

I have another app running on http://localhost:8081/ that does not promp for credentials when I use this:

```
<img alt="use-credentials"
src="http://localhost:8080/img/turtle.png"
crossOrigin="use-credentials">
```

but this image is not rendreing, instead I get the error:

Access to image at 'http://localhost:8080/img/turtle.png' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have read all the articles, blogs, questions and watched the videos, but I cannot find a single working example on how to use crossorigin use-credentials, all the examples out there are using anonymous and explaining use-credentials very vaguely.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250068/discussion-on-question-by-mruanova-html-img-crossoriginuse-credentials-simple).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wildcard is not allowed when Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ='*'
```

Instead specify the host:

```
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ='http://localhost:8081'
```

Source: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/218055/whats-the-reason-of-both-allow-origin-and-allow-credentials-true-header