# how to send credentials on an image with crossOrigin="use-credentials" when the http-server has "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"="true"?

Tags: html, image, http, cors, credentials

I have an http-server that requests with **Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true** (see more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647248/html-img-crossorigin-use-credentials-simple-example))

and I have an app on port 8081 that requests an image from the http-server on port 8080

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/img/turtle.png" crossOrigin="use-credentials" alt="alt">
```

currently the browser prompts for the username and password in a modal dialog (see screenshot attached) but I would like to set the **username=test** and **password=image** in the HTML, but I do not understand how the HTML IMG tag will pass through the header of the request,

is it even possible? or it this related to HTTPS and certificates?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not provide an API that makes that possible.

Consider using cookie based authentication (instead of Basic Auth) and redirecting through a single-sign-on style login system to set the cookies instead.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: I will try https://github.com/sohamkamani/nodejs-session-cookie-example

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to send the username and password in the URI like this:

http://test:image@test/image@localhost:8080/img/turtle.png

or

http://test:image%40test%3Aimage@localhost:8080/img/turtle.png